# How to populate a DataGridView by selecting any table from combo box

Tags: c#, .net

I have used the following code for displaying names of my SQL db tables in a combo box.

Now I want that when I click on any of these table names from the combo box, my DGV populates with that table's contents.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        sqlCmd.Connection = con;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select table_name from information_schema.tables";

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

        DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Then I used the following code for populating my DGV but it's not working; please help.

```
private void PopulateGridView()
{
    String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strconnection);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        sqlCmd.Connection = con;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from " + comboBox1.SelectedText;

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

        DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        PopulateGridView(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? What do you mean by saying "its not working"? Do you get any error message or what?

Comment: And why do you call `PopulateGridView` method with a parameter, when the method is parameterless?

Comment: i hav debug my code...the combo box is showing the table names in my sql db...but my dgv is not populating with the contents of table i select from combo box..plzz help

Comment: so according to my code what parameters should i add to populateGridView....?...im new to c# plz help

Comment: you need to check datatable (dtrecord)   before you fetching the data into datagridview....

Comment: you have not set ValueMember of your combobox, though you are passing value in the PopulateGridView method which is as it seems a parameterless method

Comment: the code is showing error in PopulateGridView(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());.....no overload method for this

Comment: so how to correct it plzz tell  @Manish Mishra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this:
update your code in the Form Load with below:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        sqlCmd.Connection = con;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select table_name from information_schema.tables";

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "table_name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "table_name";
        con.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

so basically you have added one extra line  `comboBox1.ValueMember = "table_name";`

and make your PopulateGridView method like this:

```
   private void PopulateGridView(string tblName)
        {
            String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

            try
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

                sqlCmd.Connection = con;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from " + tblName;

                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

                DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
                dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

it has to work.
Also, I see, you are creating `SqlConnection` object everywhere, including `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

try to wrap them up in static methods i.e.

```
 - public static SqlConnection OpenConnection()
 - public static DataTable ExecuteSelectQuery(string Query)
 - public static bool ExecuteModifyQuery(string Query)
```

try to write as less amount of code as you can.

Comment: no nothing no errors no exceptions..:(   if psb can u post the whole code u have tried?

Comment: i tried same code, the one that you wrote above. anyways, inside your method PopulateGridView, after this line sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord); place this line MessageBox.Show(dtRecord.Rows.Count.ToString()); and see if the messagebox shows a number other than 0

Comment: well im a beginner...and my programming skills r not that good..plz help me i really require that rite nw

Comment: @manish mishra thnks a lot...it is not displaying any msg box..i dnt understand where am i going wrong

Comment: i've posted the entire code tht is working for me. directly copy n paste and see if it works for you. No messageBox came, is very strange, u sure no exception occured?

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help..n spending so much of ur precious time on my problem..:)

Comment: still its not displaying...but no problem i will look at it myself now..thnks for your help guys

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
        {
           string strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

                sqlCmd.Connection = con;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from " + comboBox1.SelectedValue;
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

                DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
                dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @MayuriKoul did u check the datatable ( dtrecord )